# What is /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old and can I safely delete it?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I've recently upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. A few things didn't make it across, for example the ttf-mscorefonts-installer (no idea why), and while I was trying to install them that I got a warning.

The command...

```
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

...as well as producing the usual behavior, also produced multiple instances of the warning...

```
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

There is a file with the same name but without the `.ucf-old` extension in the same directory. Is this a relic of the upgrade process? Can I just delete the "old" file?

Answer (score 8):

The file `50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old` is created by the utility ucf ["update configuration files"] which interacts with the user during the upgrade, asking whether to overwrite or retain a copy of old configuration files. The one with the suffix `.ucf-old` is the copy. It is retained for reference and can be deleted safely.

From the ucf [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/ucf.1.html):

> During the course of operations, when working with configuration
>   files,
>          ucf optionally creates copies of versions of the configuration file  in
>          question.  For  example,  a  file with the suffix ucf-old holds the old
>          version of a configuration file replaced by [the utility] ucf. [...] 
>          the maintainer scripts should consider purging  copies  of
>          the configuration file with these extensions during purge.

The behavior of ucf is described on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572976/what-to-do-now-update-just-after-install/573091#573091).

Comment: The difference between the two files is that the newer one has `"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";` added.

Comment: Thank you.  Even though it was saying it was ignoring it, I was finding that to be annoying.

Answer (score -4):

Answer:

1. `@achintya:~$ sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist /etc/apt`
2. `@achintya:~$ sudo apt-get update`
3. `@achintya:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: This does not exactly answer the questions.

Comment: This is not related to the question.